# What is the correct syntax for an iframe embed with pug

Tags: javascript, iframe, pug

I'm trying to add the sightmap embed script (below) into a pug file. I've come up with this, but it is breaking the page:

```
script(src="https://sightmap.com/embed/api.js")
iframe( id="sightmap" width="100%" height="700px" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://sightmap.com/embed/sightmaphere?enable_api=1&origin=https://www.propertydomain.com/" frameborder="0")
script.
  var embed = new SightMap.Embed('sightmap');
  embed.on('ready', function() {
  }
  embed.on('outbound.thriveKnock.click', function(event) {
      knockDoorway.openScheduling();
  }
```

Here is the original script for the iframe:

```
<!-- Engrain/Knock Map/CTA -->
<script src="https://sightmap.com/embed/api.js"></script>
<iframe id="sightmap" width="100%" height="700px" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="CURRENT-SIGHTMAP-URL-HERE?enable_api=1&origin=https://propertydomain.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Create a new embed instance, providing the IFrame id value
  var embed = new SightMap.Embed('sightmap');
  embed.on('ready', function() {
  });

  // Outbound Link API
  embed.on('outbound.thriveKnock.click', function(event) {
      // Open Knock Scheduler
      knockDoorway.openScheduling();
  });
</script>
<!-- End Engrain/Knock Map/CTA -->
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Typo. You failed to transcribe `);` … twice.

Comment: You can use https://html-to-pug.com/ to make simple translations like this.

Comment: Thank you both. @graham I'll give this pug translator a try.